# WIX VELOhaving problems to obtein a value using fetch, json

Tags: json, fetch, velo

I'm having trouble getting a value through the json function in velo.
Sorry I'm new to this, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.
This is my code:

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';
import wixFetch from 'wix-fetch';


    export function button1_click(event) {
     fetch("https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SF43787/datos/2020-01-01/2020-01-02?token=81a6706a64a09f9f3d808155ad53195f7db0a1e9826a176e805076353257ba2c", {"method": "get"})
      .then( (httpResponse) => {
        let url = httpResponse.url;
        let statusCode = httpResponse.status;
        let statusText = httpResponse.statusText;
        let headers = httpResponse.headers;
        let bodyUsed = httpResponse.bodyUsed;
        $w("#input1").value=statusText;
        $w('#input2').value= url;
        
    
    
        if (httpResponse.ok) {
          return httpResponse.json();
        }
        else {
          return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
        }
      } )
      .then( (json) => {
        console.log(json.dato);
        $w("#input2").value='JSON PROMISE OK'+json.dato
         } )
      .catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      } );
```

[image: results]

The result for input 1 is: `JSON PROMISE OK undefined`

I can't solve it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're having is because you're referring to the returned JSON object incorrectly. There's no `json.dato`, the object returned based on your code snippet looks like this:
[object returned from https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SF43787/datos/2020-01-01/2020-01-02?token=81a6706a64a09f9f3d808155ad53195f7db0a1e9826a176e805076353257ba2c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvUrV.png)

So in order to get the dato property specifically you should refer to something like `json.bmx.series[0].datos[0].dato`.
There are a few ways to learn about the structure of the returned object from the resource you are fetching, one way I'd like to suggest you use is Preview or Functional Testing (which is currently available only in backend functions), you can learn more about these tools [here](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-testing-and-debugging-your-code).

On a different note, the code you've written seems to be mostly like a copy&paste from a few of Velo's examples and I believe there are some unnecessary parts in it. For example, you're not using wixFetch so there's no need to import. Neither do you use the `statusCode`, `headers` and `bodyUsed` variables.

Comment: Thank you so much, I follow your advise and i works perfectly fine. Now I can get the value.